# an example of MDN Function.prototype.apply()

Tags: javascript

The follow example refer from MDN :

```js
Function.prototype.construct = function(aArgs) {
  console.warn('Function construct')
  var oNew = Object.create(this.prototype);
  this.apply(oNew, aArgs);
  return oNew;
};

function MyConstructor() {
  console.warn('MyConstructor')
  for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
    this["property" + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
  }
}

var myArray = [4, "Hello world!", false];
var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);
```

the result is :

```
Function construct  
MyConstructor
```

Why the `this.apply(oNew, aArgs);` called `MyConstructor ()`?

Thanks for answers

Comment: `MyConstructor.construct()` invocation calls `this.apply(oNew, aArgs);` within the function body

Comment: Sorry I can't understand. I mean Why the `MyConstructor` output without calling `MyConstructor ()`

Comment: What does the currying function have to do with your question?

Comment: @junlin Because `this` refers to `MyConstructor` inside a `MyConstructor.construct()` method invocation

Comment: be careful with your `currying` function, because it has some weird logic/behaviour; one I would not expect from a curried function. The function adds arguments to `args` as long as you feed it some, and only runs `fn` once you call it without passing any arguments. It doesn't stop, when you have "enough" args to satisfy `fn`, and it may never stop adding items to `args`, and never call `fn`, as long as you always call it with at least one argument. There may be a use case for such a function, but I would not call that "curried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the `this.apply(oNew, aArgs);` called `MyConstructor ()`?

Let's go step by step:

- When the interpreter reaches to `MyConstructor.construct(myArray);`, it tries to find property `construct` on object `MyConstructor`. The interpreter cannot find it. It then goes one step through its prototype chain (the internal `[[Prototype]]` property), i.e. the object `Function.prototype`. It does have it! The lookup process stops and start interpreting `construct` function. This way of looking up properties is called [prototype inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).
- In this case (not always), `this` inside that `construct` function refers to the `MyConstructor` object (remember all functions are objects). So `this.prototype` is the object `Function.prototype`.
- [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) gets an object and creates a new object with the given object as its immediate parent prototype object. So `oNew` is an ordinary object having the same prototype as `this`.
- `this.apply(oNew, aArgs);` Here recall that `this` *is* `MyConstructor`. So this statement invokes `MyConstructor` function and passes `oNew` as its `this` and `aArgs` as its arguments.
- When `MyConstructor` is invoked its `this` refers to `oNew` and its `arguments` is an array containing `aArgs`.

---

The second example:

What's `[].push.apply(args, arguments);`? Let's go :)

- `[]` creates an empty array literal (which is an object too).
- Since `[]` on its own doesn't have any properties, `[].push` refers to the `push` object (remember functions are objects) on its parent through its prototype chain.
- `[].push.apply` invokes that function and passes `args` as its `this` and `arguments` as its arguments.

You can instead of `[].push.apply()` use `Array.prototype.push.apply()`. Those `push` objects refer to the same object.

Comment: Good, I get it. `this` in `Function.prototype.construct()` refers `MyConstructor` object. So `this.apply()` is equal to `MyConstructor()`

Comment: I had move the currying question example to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745206/js-currying-function-example).  Please have a look.

Comment: Nitpick: the hidden slot is called [[prototype]], not `__proto__`. That's a deprecated getter.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the `this.apply(oNew, aArgs);` called `MyConstructor ()`?

`MyConstructor.construct()` invocation calls `this.apply(oNew, aArgs);` within the function body of `.construct`, which is set as a property of `Function.prototype`

> Why the `MyConstructor` output without calling `MyConstructor`

`.construct` is defined at `Function.prototype`. `MyConstructor` is a function which inherits `.construct`, `MyConstructor.construct()` call `.construct` function defined at `Function.prototype`, where `MyConstructor` has the same `.prototype`

```js
Function.prototype.construct = function (aArgs) {
console.warn('Function construct')
  var oNew = Object.create(this.prototype);
  this.apply(oNew, aArgs);
  return oNew;
};

function MyConstructor () {
    console.warn('MyConstructor')
    for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
        this["property" + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
    }
}

console.log(MyConstructor.construct === Function.prototype.construct);
// var myArray = [4, "Hello world!", false];
// var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `apply` on a method changes its execution context. So the `this` keyword will refer to `oNew` instead of the constructor. See this post for more information: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2265-changing-the-execution-context-of-javascript-functions-using-call-and-apply.htm.