# js currying function example

Tags: javascript, currying

How to understand the `currying` function?

How the `newSum` and `newFind` works?

```js
var currying = function(fn) {
  var args = [];
  return function() {
    if (!!arguments.length) {
      [].push.apply(args, arguments); // What's the meaning of this writing?
      return arguments.callee;
    } else {
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
}

// accumulation currying
var sum = (function(num){
  var ret = 0;
  return function(){
    for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
        ret += arguments[i];
    }
    return ret;
  }
})();
var newSum = currying(sum);
newSum(1)(2)(3)(4)()  // 10

// element find currying
var find = function(arr, el){
  return arr.indexOf(el) !== -1;
}

var newFind = currying(find)([1,2,3]);
newFind(1);
newFind(2);
```

Comment: where did you get this code? And what exactly don't you understand/need clarified? (after https://stackoverflow.com/q/46742196/6567275)

Comment: `[].push.apply(args, arguments);` does basically `for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i) args.push(arguments[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

The `currying` function, and gets a function as an argument, and returns a new function, that when invoked:

- If arguments are provided, they are accumulated in the `args` array
- If arguments are not provided, the original function is called with all accumulated arguments.

So, if we look at this call for example: `newSum(1)(2)(3)(4)()` - there are 5 function invocations:

- Calling `newSum` with `1`. Getting the curried function with 1 accumulated.
- Calling the curried function with 2 - getting the same function with 1 and 2 accumulated, and so on for 3 and 4.
- Calling the curried function without arguments - applying all the accumulated arguments (1, 2, 3, 4) to the original `sum` function - and getting the correct value, 10.

About `[].push.apply(args, arguments);` and `fn.apply(this, args);`: `apply` is a method on `Function.prototype` that basically lets you call a function, supplying a context object and an array of arguments. So basically `[].push.apply(...)` is a trick of concatenating an array into another array, in our case, concat `arguments` (which is the list of arguments provided to a function upon invocation) into `args` (the accumulating list of arguments). `fn.apply(this, args);` is simply calling the original function with all the accumulated arguments. You can read more about it in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

By the way, `newFind(1);` and `newFind(2);` both return a function, that will look for the index of the element only when invoked, meaning `newFind(1)() === true`